# Picture download URL is not showing in Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-storage

the profilePictureUri keeps on showing

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A31content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A31

even if the uid of the picture uploaded to firebase storage already match the data saved in firestore. have tried several tweak but it doesn't work

```
fun uploadProfilePicture(firestore: FirebaseFirestore, uri: Uri) {
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
    if (uid == null) {
        Log.e(Profile.TAG, "User is not authenticated.")
        return
    }
    val imageRef = storageRef.child("profile_pictures/$uid")
    val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(uri)

    uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            task.exception?.let {
                throw it
            }
        }
        imageRef.downloadUrl
    }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val downloadUrl = task.result.toString()
            // save the download URL to Firestore as a string
            firestore.collection("userss").document(uid).set(
                mapOf(
                    "profilePictureUri" to downloadUrl.toString()
                )
            ).addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(Profile.TAG, "Profile picture uploaded and saved to Firestore.")
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e(Profile.TAG, "Error saving profile picture download URL to Firestore.", e)
            }
        } else {
            task.exception?.let { e ->
                Log.e(Profile.TAG, "Error uploading profile picture to Firebase Storage.", e)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun UserButton_Profile(
    ownerName: String,
    namauserss: String,
    firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    profilePictureUri : Uri?
) {
    val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!
    val uid = user.uid

    // Upload the profile picture to Firebase Storage and save the download URL to Firestore
    if (profilePictureUri != null) {
        uploadProfilePicture(firestore, profilePictureUri)
    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            val userss = hashMapOf(
                "ownerName" to ownerName,
                "namauserss" to namauserss
            )
            try {
                firestore.collection("userss")
                    .document(uid)
                    .set(userss)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d(Profile.TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: $uid")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.w(Profile.TAG, "Error adding document", e)
                    }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(Profile.TAG, "Error writing to database", e)
                throw e
            }

        },
        enabled = true,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(all = 16.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Profile",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried converting the URI to string first but it still showing the same thing. I expect it to show https:// something that will redirect to url of the profile picture the associated user has uploaded

Comment: Is that content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A31 the image URL of the document?

Comment: @AlexMamo i dont think so....